# make asp.net control visible true at clientside using onClick peroperty of LinkButton

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax

I am using ASP.Net Controls like (TextBox, Drop down List) in my UserControl Page and all are make invisible for this i am using (Edit ). There is a Link Button for Edit in the same page. I want to make it visible at clientside. can any one suggest how should i do. or any other way to make it.

Comment: Typically the edit button will cause a postback where you can then set the other controls Visible = True

Comment: Thanx, Yes It is postbacking. So that i need some thing client side which will not postback. and I have more than 20 controls which will be editable separately. So I need a client side function to apply onClick event. is there any way???

Comment: Have you tried to use [AJAX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee341002.aspx) functionality? Enclosing your controls into an [UpdatePanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.aspx) can help you turn your edit button to do a client-side call instead of the usual postback.

Comment: you will need to reconstruct your page all over again to make it able to work all base on Ajax Calls and client side things thats for clean way for your work but for your issue i think if there is a way for what you want it will be painful and have many deffects :)

Answer (score 4):

To do this with Javascript you'll want to remove the OnClick attribute of the LinkButton and use the OnClientClick attribute to call a Javascript function instead:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lb_link_button" runat="server" Text="Click Me" OnClientClick="return ToggleShowHide()"/>
```

Here's a corresponding Javascript function to show/hide a control named my_control using its style.display property:

```
<script type="text/javascript">        
    function ToggleShowHide() {
        var control = document.getElementById("<%= my_control.ClientID %>");
        if (control.style.display == "none") { control.style.display = "block"; }
        else { control.style.display = "none"; }
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

You can reference the control(s) to show/hide in various ways, this is just a simple example.

Note, the control(s) to set visible/invisible must *not* have their Visible property set as false, instead they should be declared with a display:none; style as follows:

```
<asp:Control runat="server" ID="my_control" Visible="true" style="display:none;"/>
```